# Binding boolean properties of a Set of a certain class to checkboxes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-binding

I wish to get a list of countries per continent (from my database) as labels with checkboxes which enable specific countries to be shown/used in my webapp.

Here is how it visually looks like.

[image]

Therefore I use the `Continent`class:

```
@Entity
public class Continent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "continent")
    private Set<Country> countries;

    // Getters, equals, hashCode...
}
```

And the `Country` class as well:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "continentid")
    private Continent continent;
    
    private boolean enabled; // THE CHECKBOX
   
    // Getters, equals, hashCode...
}
```

Then I initialize a binder for `Continent` within the appropriate controller and add the requested continent (using a clean URL for parameter) as an object to my `ModelAndView` (GET):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/continent")
public class LocaleController {

    private final LocaleService localeService;
    
    @Autowired
    LocaleController(LocaleService localeService) {
        this.localeService = localeService;
    }
    
    @InitBinder("continent")
    void initBinderContinent(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.initDirectFieldAccess();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(path="{continent}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ModelAndView readContinent(@PathVariable Continent continent) {
        return new ModelAndView("continent",
                "continent", continent);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(path="{continent}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String editContinent(@PathVariable Continent continent) {
        //TODO hasErrors etc.
        localeService.updateContinent(continent);
        return "redirect:/continents";
    }
}
```

Within the `body`of my JSP-file I write (using taglib for Spring Forms and the JSTL core as well):

```
<form:form commandName='continent' id='continentform'>
    
</form:form>
  <h1>${continent.name}</h1>
  <!-- SelectAll and UnselectAll buttons, other HTML tags -->
  <c:forEach var="country" items="${continent.countries}" varStatus="loop">
    <form:checkbox path="countries['${loop.index}'].enabled"/>
    <form:label path="countries['${loop.index}'].enabled">
      ${country.name}
    </form:label>
  </c:forEach>
```

But this doesn't work:

**First:** the `loop.index` does not correspond to the index of `Set<Country> countries` for current `country` within the loop; I know it because `country.name` is not equal to `countries['${loop.index}'].name`

**Second:** the label `for=` attribute doesn't correspond to the appropriate checkbox attribute `id=`.

**Third** `localeService.updateContinent(continent)` calls `continentDAO.save(continent)`(`ContinentDAO` is an interface extending `JpaRepository<Continent, Long>`) but does not update the enabled state of the country.

What's my mistake?

Comment: A `Set` isn't an indexed collection, so trying to make that accessible through an index isn't going to work. You have to use an indexed collection for this.

Comment: You mean to make it modifiable and using countries.get(index) ?

Comment: List<Country> doesn't work too.

Comment: You cannot use a `@PathVariable` for binding only a `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestBody`. Assuming you have Spring Data JPA setup correctly you are basically retrieving the object from the database, do nothing with and persist it again. (There is no binding going to happen).

Comment: Now I understand the reason. Thank you! I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the the **first problem**, I do not return a TreeSet of `Set<Country> countries` within `Continent` class anymore (I just return `countries`).

To solve the **second problem** I've edited my JSP `<c:forEach>` inner content:

```
<c:forEach var="country" items="${continent.countries}" varStatus="loop">
  <form:checkbox path="countries['${loop.index}'].enabled" cssClass="medium"
          label="${country.name}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

To solve the **third problem** I've edited the `editContinent` function within my `LocaleController` and it works now:

```
 @RequestMapping(path="{continent}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String editContinent(@Valid Continent continent, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        //TODO hasErrors etc.
        localeService.updateContinent(continent);
        return "redirect:/continents";
 }
```

Thanks to M. Deinum for very useful comments.